# capture data between 1st and second occurrence of the pattern in a loop

Tags: linux, unix

I need the data between the pattern in the file

Data in File is as follows

```
cat file1
# Wed 06-02-2017
field1=abc
field2=xyz
field3=ijk
# Wed 06-02-2017
field1=123
field2=456
field3=789
# Wed 06-02-2017
field1=a1a
field2=c1c
field3=d1d
```

I want to run the loop and in first loop find the data between 1st and 2nd occurrence of pattern <#> and then in second loop i want data between 2nd and 3rd pattern <#> and so on.

Below is the code written for the same, but its not working

```
cat caturedata
#!/bin/sh

lastlineno=$(wc -l file1 | awk {'print$1'})
echo $lastlineno
for (( i=1;i<=$lastlineno;i=a))
do
        echo "Inside Loop : $i"
        sed '"$i",/#/d;/#/,$d' file1
        temp=$(sed '"$i",/#/d;/#/,$d' file1 | wc |awk '{print $1}')
        a=i+temp+1
done
```

I am trying to find the last line number of the file
then run a loop between 1st and last line number
then run sed command to capture data between line number first and second occurrence of the pattern
then identify the next line number to start with

Output should be as below

```
Inside Loop : 1
field1=abc
field2=xyz
field3=ijk
Inside Loop : 5
field1=123
field2=456
field3=789
Inside Loop : 9
field1=a1a
field2=c1c
field3=d1d
```

Comment: Can you show us what output you want from file1?

Comment: Output should be as below    
Inside Loop : 1
field1=abc
field2=xyz
field3=ijk
Inside Loop : 5
field1=123
field2=456
field3=789
Inside Loop : 9
field1=a1a
field2=c1c
field3=d1d

Answer (score 0):

You can first merge the same block splited by `# Wed xx-xxx-2017`  using awk:

```
awk '{if($0 !~ /^#/){printf",%s",$0} else {printf "\n%s",$0}}' xxx.txt 

# Wed 06-02-2017,field1=abc,field2=xyz,field3=ijk
# Wed 06-02-2017,field1=123,field2=456,field3=789
# Wed 06-02-2017,field1=a1a,field2=c1c,field3=d1d
```

and then do further comparison

Note that there is a blank line before the first line of data

Comment: No this is not what i want. I want to extract a block between the pattern '#' and need to compare its values with other data, thats why i am running loop.. the way i want is to capture data field1=abc
field2=xyz
field3=ijk , compare the values in this field and then in the next run of for loop capture data field1=123
field2=456
field3=789 compare their values and so on

Comment: does the data have same number of fields in each block?

Comment: No, that is not the case, some block has 6 fields , some have 7 etc

Answer (score 0):

This is a skeleton script which could help:

```
cat file1 | while read line; do
  # echo "              --read $line"
  if [ "$goahead" = "yes" ]; then
    while true; do
      if [[ "$line" == \#* ]]; then
        echo "break on marker $line"
        break
      else
        echo "   process line: $line"
      fi
      read line
      # echo "  read $line"
      if [ -z "$line" ]; then break; fi
    done
  fi

  if [[ "$line" == \#* ]]; then
    echo "start on marker $line"
    goahead="yes"
  fi
done
```

The output, with your data (but I have made the headers each different), is:

```
start on marker # Wed 06-02-2017
   process line: field1=abc
   process line: field2=xyz
   process line: field3=ijk
break on marker # Wed 07-02-2017
start on marker # Wed 07-02-2017
   process line: field1=123
   process line: field2=456
   process line: field3=789
break on marker # Wed 08-02-2017
start on marker # Wed 08-02-2017
   process line: field1=a1a
   process line: field2=c1c
   process line: field3=d1d
```